# Facebook before and after like fan page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Seems like Facebook changed a lot of things recently. I would like to know how to show a custom page if the user has not liked the Fan page. If the user likes the page I will show them the Fan page wall. How to do this? I searched around but seems like Facebook reinvented itself.

Thanks.

Comment: When hasn't Facebook changed stuff and continually broken stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change what a visitor sees in your page settings...
manage permissions
 - default landing tab ( pick your page here )

also - 
I created this php script that shows like and non-like content to users.

Tutorial / Example
http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=100

GIT Project
https://github.com/DrewDahlman/FBVersion

Comment: I cannot see Canvas URL in the Facebook App setting anymore :(. They have changed the Facebook Apps.

Comment: Aaah....now I cannot add tab to my page. They want me to run a URL with App ID and nextURI to add the tab. Why they had to make this so difficult. It keeps saying 'redirect_uri is not owned by the application.' Not sure what this means :(.

Comment: You should be able to just fill in the fields..

Page Tab Name: YOU TAB NAME
 
Page Tab URL: http://www.YOUR_URL.com/
 
Secure Page Tab URL:https://www.YOUR_PAGEURL.com/
 
Page Tab Edit URL:XXXX NOT NEEDED

Once thats done save.
got to your application page and click "add to page" and select the page you want to add the tab to. then in your page's settings in manage permissions select the tab from the drop down...

Answer (score 0):

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
   //User is not a fan
}
```

Source: [Determine If The User Likes (Fan Of) Your Facebook Page When Landing On Your Page Tab](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/)

Comment: OK but what I am confused is how to add the custom page. There is no Canvas URL anymore in the applications. Do I need to create a new tab? I cannot do this without tab?